# Is any arbitrary intersection of absorbing sets absorbing?

Tags: functional-analysis

It is easy to show that the *finite* intersection of absorbing sets is absorbing: if the $S_k$ are absorbing and $\mathbf{x}\in X$, then there are $t_k>0$ for which $\mathbf{x}\in t_kS_k$, and naturally
$$\mathbf{x}\in\min_k t_k \bigcap_{k=1}^n S_k$$
as wanted.

The proof naturally breaks down if there are infinitely many $S_k$, which begs the question: is any arbitrary intersection of absrobing sets absorbing?

Comment: Consider the collection of open balls of radius $1/n$ centered at $0$. Their intersection is the single point $\{0\}$.

Comment: Should there not be $\max_k \left [ t_k \right ] \equiv \tilde t$ instead, so that we can conclude that $x\in \tilde t \cap_k S_k$ ?